# Check if element exists in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if an element exists if the element is created by `.append()` method?
`$('elemId').length` doesn't work for me.

Comment: `.length` works just fine, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/A9zW2/ if you did use `#` post your code and we'll see what you done wrong.

Comment: Use $('#selector').length and $('.selector').length for id and class selector. $('#selector option').size() to check dropdown size.

Answer (score 2028, accepted):

> `$('elemId').length` doesn't work for
>   me.

You need to put `#` before element id:

```
$('#elemId').length
---^
```

---

With vanilla JavaScript, you don't need the hash (`#`) e.g. `document.getElementById('id_here')` , however when using jQuery, you do need to put hash to target elements based on `id` just like CSS.

Comment: CSS selectors are used therefore "#elementId" selects by element. "elementId" would actually select all emenets whose _tags_ are named "elementId"

Comment: @trejder Most likely the poster was unaware of Vanilla JS and when they said "vanilla JavaScript" they actually *meant* base JavaScript ("vanilla" as in "plain", "unadorned).

Comment: @trejder Looks like "Vanilla JS" is exactly the same as base Javascript anyway (the downloaded file is always empty) - someone just decided to make a sales pitch for base Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, that website is mocking the need for a framework called "Vanilla JS" which is nothing but JavaScript itself. @trejder should read a little more carefully.

Comment: You "don't need the hash" only if you use the wrong function. `document.querySelector('#id_here')` requires the hash sign just as much as the jQuery equivalent `$('#id_here')`.

Comment: why not use '$('#elemId')==null' ?

Comment: I really dislike this answer because it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: does `$('#elemId ul li').length` work?

Answer (score 500):

Try to check the length of the selector, if it returns you something then the element must exists else not.

```
 if( $('#selector').length )         // use this if you are using id to check
{
     // it exists
}


 if( $('.selector').length )         // use this if you are using class to check
{
     // it exists
}
```

Comment: I find this approach to be so unintuitive.  It's almost like asking how to determine if a number is negative, and then someone telling you that you need to write the code in assembly and then manually twiddle some bits in the CPU's registers, instead of simply calling a method like .isNegative().  Checking the value of a 'length' property clutters things up.  I'd rather see something like a .exists() method, which is instantly recognizable while scanning through code.

Comment: in some ways, jquery made leaps and bounds for making javascript more accessible, but is still very far from being idiomatic

Comment: This solution is perfectly intuitive. The length property tells you how many elements match the query. What is not intuitive or straight-forward about that?

Comment: You could just write a more intuitive function:`function exists(elementName) {
  return $(elementName).length;
 }`

Comment: This throws an exception in the console. `jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 211):

Try this:

```
if ($("#mydiv").length > 0){
  // do something here
}
```

The length property will return zero if element does not exists.

Comment: No need for > 0, if it's 0 it will evaluate to false.

Comment: I can't get this to work without including `> 0`. Any ideas why that might happen?

Comment: sorry for mistaken downvote ill fix it later

Comment: @wessamelmahdy verbosity can increase clarity, which can reduce the cognitive cost of maintenance

Comment: `if ($("#mydiv").length === 0){` because types

Comment: Does not work if element is not in DOM.

Answer (score 92):

> How do I check if an element exists

```
if ($("#mydiv").length){  }
```

If it is `0`, it will evaluate to `false`, anything more than that `true`.

There is no need for a greater than, less than comparison.

Comment: that's not working for me. browser I use is firefox 32.02.

Comment: feel free to paste your snippet

Comment: thanks, no problem anymore. I have replace it with this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/21801090/2232458

Answer (score 32):

your `elemId` as its name suggests, is an `Id` attribute, these are all you can do to check if it exists:

**Vanilla JavaScript:** in case you have more advanced selectors:

```
//you can use it for more advanced selectors
if(document.querySelectorAll("#elemId").length){}

if(document.querySelector("#elemId")){}

//you can use it if your selector has only an Id attribute
if(document.getElementById("elemId")){}
```

**jQuery:**

```
if(jQuery("#elemId").length){}
```

Comment: You don't need  `!= null` as `querySelector` will always return `null` (which is falsey) or an element

Comment: I would still use ```if (document.querySelector("elemId") != null )``` just to improve code readability

Comment: @Mrinmoy your mindset is either coming from Java or C#. In JavaScript we know we have seven falsy values (0, -0, null, undefined, '', NaN and false) and considering those falsy values `if (document.querySelector("elemId") != null )` has no effect in writing a more readable code. In JavaScript world instead of keeping your mindset from structural programming languages like Java or C# it is highly recommended to get to know the conventions of JavaScript community. For a JavaScript developer in this specific case `!= null` is totally redundant and much less readable.

Comment: @MehranHatami , so you are agreeing that the code is readable only by a javaScripter, still he will be left confused if  ```querySelector()``` returns ```null or 0``` or any of the other 5 values. ```querySelectorAll() ``` and jQuery has a different return value when it dont find an element.  Please consider that people these days work on polyglot of techs and frameworks so making things more readable is sure to benefit. By the way I am more a javascripter than a java/golang programmer

Comment: @Mrinmoy I agree that this is a debatable topic BUT what I said was not my opinion than a fact. in my team, if I see a pull request which has ` != null ` I don't approve it. Although it is a convention BUT it has become a rule, sort of. To me what matters the most is to make sure the developer in my team knows the basics and their code is consistent with no redundancy. ` != null` to me is like ` != false` which is a valid condition for an if statement BUT it redundant in itself.

Comment: @Mrinmoy  in JavaScript when we say `if (a){}` it means `a` exists or is not falsy and comparing it with null is valid ONLY when you want to validate the value to be specifically `null` which is not the case in this example. You are free to use both BUT I wouldn't approve it if any of my developers use ` != null` for this kind of cases, which means its being a convention has some effect in making it more or less readable.

Comment: @MehranHatami so did you invented any linter rule which look for ```!= null``` or can you point me to any famous linters that have this condition baked in. if I use ```!== null``` what wud you do? JS has a strict type checks, would you advise against using it? there are functions that returns ```null, 0 or undefined``` and each implies a different reason so ```if (a){ }``` wont cut for all the cases. plus its a good thing to educate ur developers on what the function is returning rather than leaving them with a guess work to figure out which falsy or non-falsy value they are dealing with

Answer (score 20):

You can also use array-like notation and check for the first element.
The first element of an empty array or collection is simply `undefined`, so you get the "normal" javascript truthy/falsy behaviour:

```
var el = $('body')[0];
if (el) {
    console.log('element found', el);
}
if (!el) {
    console.log('no element found');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use native JS to test for the existence of an object:

```
if (document.getElementById('elemId') instanceof Object){
    // do something here
}
```

Don't forget, jQuery is nothing more than a sophisticated (and very useful) wrapper around native Javascript commands and properties

Comment: You don't need `instanceof Object`

Answer (score -20):

If you have a class on your element, then you can try the following:

```
if( $('.exists_content').hasClass('exists_content') ){
 //element available
}
```

Comment: If element did not exists, how can you check for the class.

Comment: wow did not see that answer coming

Comment: This answer should get a golden badge for the most funniest answer of SO :))

Comment: This answer is so usefull because it tells you what to not do.