# Check block existence by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I know if there is a block with class "media" on the page?

```
if(<div class="media"></div> exist in current page){
//then do something
}
```

This code doesn't work:

```
if($(".media")){ //do }
```

Comment: lol, is this a test of fastest-response question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery check if element exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/jquery-check-if-element-exists)

Comment: This question has been asked many many time before - did you try searching before asking it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check `if ($('.media').length)`.

`$(...)` returns a jQuery object, which will always be "truthy", even when empty.
However, if it's empty, its `length` property will be `0`, which is "falsy".

You can also be more explicit and write `if ($('.media').length > 0)`.

Comment: I would add `> 0` to make it more obvious.

Comment: Looks like you out drew everyone. ;-)

Comment: @Rooney , you dont.. i makes it more readble for some people I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can use .length to check for existance

```
   if ($(".media").length)
    {//do something}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is:

```
if ($("div.media").length > 0) {
    // Then do something.
}
```

Hint: use the tag name `div` before the class `.media` because it is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($(".media").length > 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($(".media").length){ //do }
```