# jQuery if H1:contains a word do something

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

I've used the `contains()`function successfully, but never have used it with an `if-statement`.  My below code doesn't seem to work when it should.  I am basically saying if `H1` contains the word "true", do something, if not do something else.  Currently it only shows the first bit of code no matter what is in the `H1`.. it never shows the `else` part.

```
<H1>This h1 contains the word Star</H1>

if ($("H1:contains('True')")) {
    var test= "<div>IT DID CONTAIN THE WORD TRUE!</div>";
    $('h1').append(test);

} else {
    var test= "<div>IT DID <b>NOT</b> CONTAIN THE WORD TRUE!</div>";
    $('h1').append(test);                     
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [if contains certain text, then run jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309870/if-contains-certain-text-then-run-jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check the `length` property of the resulting collection:

```
if ($("H1:contains('True')").length) {
    ...
```

Since `$("H1:contains('True')")` will return an object and objects *always* evaluate to truthy.

Comment: lol duh, thank you very much I've been looking at the code to long =p

Answer (score 1):

`$("H1:contains('True')")` is a selector. It returns a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), not a boolean. To check that the selector found any objects, [check the `length` property](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F):

```
if ($("H1:contains('True')").length) {
    // stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($("H1:contains('True')").length > 0) {
   var test= "<div>IT DID CONTAIN THE WORD TRUE!</div>";
   $('h1').append(test);                     
} else {
   var test= "<div>IT DID <b>NOT</b> CONTAIN THE WORD TRUE!</div>";
   $('h1').append(test);                     
}
```

Comment: The test would either be `> 0` or `>= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

With the contains, it gives back a list.

Refer to this for a solution:

[if contains certain text, then run jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309870/if-contains-certain-text-then-run-jquery/6310319)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$("H1:contains('True')")` always returns `true` because it is always an object.  What you really want to check is if it contains elements.

```
if ($("H1:contains('True')").length) {
```

Now it will return the else part.

Note: I believe that `:contains` is case-sensitive.