# .contains() throws an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'contains' "

Tags: jquery, contains

I do have a working code (with :contains), but I couldn't make it work with .contains(), and I would like to ask why.
HTML:

```
<div id="quiz_score_percent">Your score: <em class="placeholder">100</em> %</div>
<div id="quiz_summary">
<p>quiz feedback</p>
```

JS (working, doesn't need change):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if ($("#quiz_score_percent").has(":contains('100')").length) {
    console.log("test");
    $("#quiz_summary").append("<p>test text</p>");

}

});
```

But with `.contains()` :

```
if ($("#quiz_score_percent").contains('100')){/* execute */}
```

it throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'contains'

JS fiddle here:
[JS fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/5xMTS/1/)

**Why doesn't .contains() work?**
The accepted [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309870/if-contains-certain-text-then-run-jquery) wouldn't work for me...

Comment: Because there is no `contains()` method in jQuery. Perhaps you were using a plugin that provided one, but there is no such thing out of the box.

Comment: So I completely misunderstood this? --> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/

Comment: Yup, this is not the same thing, and does not replicate the functionality of the `:contains()` selector (it deals with element relationships, not content).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:contains` and `.contains()` are two different animals

- `:contains` will check if a certain text ist contained in the inner HTML of the selector.
- `$.contains(container, contained)` checks if a given element (the second parameter) is a child of the selector (the first parameter). `100` is not a HTML node/jQuery element. (thx for the hint, Frédéric!)

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/ and http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/.

Comment: That would be `$.contains()`, then, not plain `contains()` (i.e. it applies to the global jQuery object, not to element sets).

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
if ($("#quiz_score_percent").contains('100') == true){/* execute */}
```

Comment: How does this help with an error message which reads, *"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] **has no method** 'contains'"*?