# How to set up javascript/jquery code for whole site or one page or some of both?

Tags: jquery, file

Can someone explain this to me. I have 1 js file on my site, using mainly jQuery, all my js code uses elements that are on all pages, EXCEPT for 1 js code that targets an element that is only on one page.

So when I go to that one page, I get no JavaScript errors, however when I go to any other page it gives me a `$..Undefined` error for that element. I am using a `.offset().top` code for that element. I'm assuming that's because if you only target an element that's on one page I should just include a script on that page alone and not put it in my js file??? Does that include all jquery functions or just something specific to using `.offset()` and/or others? Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Before executing any action on the element, check if it exists : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/jquery-check-if-element-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a quick check for that element in your JS file. Example, the element only on one page:

```
<span id="coolSpan">span stuff</span>
```

JS:

```
if ($("#coolSpan").length) {
    //element exists, bind the handler
    $("#coolSpan").click(function() {
        console.log("I exist!");
    });
}
```

Comment: If the element doesn't exist, your code should quietly do nothing anyway. `.offset().top`, however, will throw an error, because `$('not-an-element').offset()` returns `null`.

Comment: It won't do anything, if it doesn't exist, it'll skip over this, yes?

Comment: It will do nothing if the element doesn't exist for event binding - think about when people forget to wrap their event binding code inside a document.ready function - no errors get thrown

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is write my js pages like so:

```
var initMyFunction = function(){
     *code for initMyFunction*
};

var initMyOtherFunction = function(){
     *code for initMyOtherFunction*
};
```

And then in my mark up I can call which function I want to run on that page, so long as I call it after I call my script.

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- Inits -->
<script>initMyFunction();</script>
```

It has the benefit of only running the code you need ran on that page, instead of running all your js on every page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access a function of an element that is not there, you will get an error regardless of the function you are using.

Solutions:

1. Like you said, you can put the specific code in a separate .js file and include that file only in the appropriate HTML page.
2. You could check for the element's existence and only then proceed with manipulating it. E.g.:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById("mySpecialElement");  
    if (elem) {  
        /* Element exists, it is safe to manipulate it */  
        $(elem).offset()...  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, you could put it in a `<script>` tag in that page, however you could also simply [check if the element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery) before attempting to perform your operation.