# Checking if a button exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, button

I have a .js file that is invoked by a few .jsp pages. What I need to do in this particular .js file is to invoke a certain function only if the 'save' button is present in the .jsp page. How do I check if the button exists? Currently, in the .js file the button is referred to this way:
$('button[id=save]')

How do I check if such a button exists?

Comment: you can also look into this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element exists in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)

Answer (score 19):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //javascript
    if(document.getElementById('save')){
        //your code goes here
    }
    
    //jquery
    if($('#save').length){
        //your code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 `getElementById` is enough, you could remove the jQuery part :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
if($('#save').length > 0){
    // Button exists
} else {
    // Button is not present in the DOM yet

}
```