# jQuery - If DIV is present on page then add CSS to other DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jQuery BUT I've got the basics down... At least I think I do?  I'm just not sure how to put them together for them to actually work.

**Example:**
IF (div with ID of #dynamicChat) is present on the page.  Then (div with class of .prdSection) height is 25px. Else do nothing

**What I have so far:**

```
$('#dynamicChat'){
$('.prdSection').css('height', '25px');
}
```

I don't think I'm far off... Saying that I probably am :)  Any help would be great!

*Side question - If I'm referring to a Div on a page, what would I call it?  An Element?

Thanks :)

Comment: you can always check the .length of a jq query to see if it is >0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element exists in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)

Comment: Not sure how you would consider this a duplicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if ($('#dynamicChat').length > 0) {
    $('.prdSection').css('height', '25px');
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you :) - Could you possibly explain what checking the length actually means / does? :)

Comment: length: "The number of elements in the jQuery object".  http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: length is needed, just not the > 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need the “> 0”, you can simply write:

```
if ( $('#myElement').length ) {
// it exists
}

if ( $('#dynamicChat').length ) {
$('.prdSection').css('height', '25px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of jQuery to check if that element exist :

```
if(document.getElementById('dynamicChat')){
    $('.prdSection').css('height', '25px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If (div with ID of **#dynamicChat**) is present on the page. Then (div with class of .prdSection) height is 25px, else do nothing

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        if ($('#dynamicChat').is("visible")) {
            $('.prdSection').css('height', '25px');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.