# How to check if the element exists in a div?

Tags: jquery

If i click on checkbox under activateUiHTML div , it is appending that particular  div to an another div present inside **My Orders** div

However if i uncheck the checkbox and recheck the checkbox under **activateUiHTML** , it is adding the same elemnt to the  **My Orders** div again .

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/40/

I tried to put this condition , but not sure if this is correct or not

```
if($('#addtoordersdiv'+id_attr_val).length > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: yes that condition is correct.. what do you want..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element exists in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)

Comment: This is perfectly right to check if div exist or not. and it seems to be working fine. what is your problem now?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy , i don't know why its adding the same element again under My Orders div .

Comment: The reason of your problem is duplicate id. See the id of your original checkbox, and the copied checkbox also has same id. You need to give different id, for example id_Selected etc.

Comment: Here is your working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/41/

Comment: Thanks Shaunak D , your fiddle is exactly what i needed , that if condition is perfect . Thanks once again .

Comment: But when we try to check the first checkbox again after unchecking it, its not checking the duplicate checkbox back... is that what you really need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/41/)**

Add an additional condition after your fetch ID,

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    var id_attr_val = $(this).attr("id");
    if(!$('#addtoordersdiv'+id_attr_val).length){

         //append code

    }
```

`.length` returns `0` if element does not exists.

Alternative to `!$(elem).length` you can also use `$(elem).length === 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the handler to the checkboxes inside the active div only like

```
$(document).on("click", ".activateUiHTML .checkboxclas", function (e) {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/43/

check if it already has the element or not:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked') && $("#ordersdiv").children('#addtoordersdiv'+id_attr_val).length==0) {...
```