# Check if any element with a certain class is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page contains multiple elements like this:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CcInfo.CcCheck" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CcInfo.CcCheck" data-valmsg-replace="true">Something went wrong</span>
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CcInfo.CcCheck" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Now, I'd like to check with JQuery if ANY of these elements contains text. So in this case, it's true, because the second element contains "Something went wrong".

I've tried:

```
if (!$(".field-validation-valid text-danger").is(':empty')) {
    // do work
}
```

But apparently it's not that easy.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `".field-validation-valid text-danger"` wrong selector, you want: `".field-validation-valid.text-danger"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.filter()` function to filter elements based on custom criteria. The criteria in the below example is that *the elements has some non-whitespace text*.

```js
$(function() {
  var $notEmptySpans = $(".field-validation-valid.text-danger").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/\S/) !== null;
  });
  console.log($notEmptySpans);
  if ($notEmptySpans.length > 0) {
    console.log($notEmptySpans.length + " non-empty spans found");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CcInfo.CcCheck" data-valmsg-replace="true">Something went wrong</span>
<!-- the following are considered empty -->
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CcInfo.CcCheck" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CcInfo.CcCheck" data-valmsg-replace="true"> </span>
```

Comment: @Bv202 what code you are using? Check for length or use: `if ($(".field-validation-valid.text-danger").is(':not(:empty)'))` if you find it more readable

Comment: This is still not working. Even though one element contains something, it doesn't execute the code.

Comment: Does it also check on hidden elements?

Comment: Any element or text node, visible or hidden. The flip side is that whitespace also make the element "not empty".

Comment: Is there a solution for that issue? My element text indeed contains some spaces..

Comment: @Bv202 Could you provide sample code which replicates your issue, as a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check whether there is some content then check, also your selector has a problem it should be `.field-validation-valid.text-danger`

```
if (!$(".field-validation-valid.text-danger").html().trim().length) {
    // do work
}
```

The [empty-selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) will fail if the checking element has a `[space]` as its content like `<span> </span>`

Answer (score 0):

You could just

```
if ($(".field-validation-valid.text-danger").not(':empty').length) {
    // do work
}
```

Explanation of `length`: [Check if element exists in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)

Also note you need to list classes separately. Your sample had a space between class names, which caused it to try selecting a tag name `<text-danger>`