# Play framework form helper inside bootstrap modal.Returning errors query

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

Currently i have a form helper generated form inside a bootstrap modal.
when the error checking occurs it returns to the page the modal is located but does not open the modal.Is there any way i can manipulate the the return ok() statement to automatically open the modal and show the errors or should i abandon this notion and just stick to a separate page with the form on it.

Any Suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was to:

- Pass a parameter so that it shows up in the HTML. ( https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates#If-blocks with element that has an id for this purpose)
- Check for that with JS. ( [Check if element exists in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery) )
- Auto-open the modal if necessary. ( [Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load) )

Comment: Sounds like exactly what i need.
Any available samples?

Comment: Are you comfortable with play template pages and passing parameters into them?

Comment: Im comfortable to the level of passing objects into the templates yes.

Comment: I've added some reference links.  Rather than using a whole element to signal that the modal should auto-open, you could also use an attribute of your modal.  Let me know if any step isn't straightforward enough.