# JQuery - Click button If button is present?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, button, input

I'm trying to make this possible:

Is there a way or an if statement to call this

```
$('#add-remove-buttons').find('.button').trigger('click');
```

After it detects that the #add-remove-buttons is present on the webpage?

-Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"? Will the button be added to the page dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try first check first element exist or not [Check if element exists in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)
after fire the event after exist

```
 if ($("#add-remove-buttons").length > 0)
 { 
    $("#add-remove-buttons").trigger('click');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whe you insert `$('#add-remove-buttons').trigger('click');` statement after the click handler on button then if the button exists it will trigger the action. You need not explicitly check to see if it exists

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('#add-remove-buttons').on('click', function(){
    alert('btn clicked');
  })
  $('#add-remove-buttons').trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-remove-buttons">Click</button>
```