# check id jquery object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if a jquery object is null  to use it this way

```
var reminder_history_div = $(".history-container");
        if(reminder_history_div)
            reminder_history_div.scrollTop(reminder_history_div[0].scrollHeight);
```

but `reminder_history_div` is not null or empty its and object ,with some info ,what is the correct way to check if is empty?maybe:

```
if(reminder_history_div.length > 0)
```

Comment: You are trying to check if it contains any text?

Comment: no,only check if there is an object with class `.history-container` to make some action

Comment: Are you trying to select elements with jquery and then test if jquery returned na object or you just want to check if empty for any javascript object ?

Comment: Did you try the last line in your question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use length to check if element is present or not refer [Check if element exists in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)

```js
$('.check').click(function(e){

if($('.history-container').length>0)
console.log('Div history-container exist')
else
console.log('Div history-container does not exist')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="history-container">
some text
</div>
<button class="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: We don't answer duplicates, we use the built-in "vote/flag to close as such"

Answer (score 1):

Example:

Check an object to see if it's empty.

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}); // true
jQuery.isEmptyObject({ foo: "bar" }); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

check if your content is empty or not and if it exists

```
const reminder_history_div = $(".history-container").html(); //OR val() 

if(!reminder_history_div){
  console.log("empty");
} else {
    console.log("not empty");
}



if($(".history-container").length >= 1){
      console.log("exists");
    } else {
      console.log("don't exists")
    }
```