# Cannot get the element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I know it is very simple but I didn't get it right. Would someone help me.
I need to get the hidden field value but it looks like I didn't get the element. The function is run because the alert box show 'run'. The alert in if statement didn't execute. 
I searched website [Check if element exists in jQuery [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery) . I still find nothing what is wrong on my code. Would someone help me. Thanks.

There is my hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdID" runat="server" value="hd"/>
```

The jQuery function:

```
function showMe() 
{
   alert('run');
   if ($('#hdID').length){
      alert( $('#hdID').val()); 
   } else {
      alert('no element'); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.Net, `runat="server"` elements that do not have `ClientIdMode="static"` specified will have their IDs rewritten<sup>†</sup>. As such, I'd expect that your HiddenField does **not** have an ID of `hdID`.

**If this is not a repeated element** (i.e. it is not in a `Repeater`, `GridView`, etc), then you can simply add `ClientIdMode="static"` to prevent this ID rewrite from occurring:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdID" ClientIdMode="Static"  runat="server"  value="hd"/>
```

**If this *is* a repeated element**, then you cannot use this technique, as it will result in duplicate IDs. In such a case, you'd likely need to provide the surrounding intentions to figure out the best method. It could be using `ClientIdMode="Predictable"` to append an index, or simply using a class selector instead.

---

<sup>† It's also possible to override the default at the page or configuration level.</sup>

Comment: I tried to add ClientIdMode="static". It doesn't work.

Comment: @user819774 As a last resort, try `Static`, case-sensitive. Otherwise there is something else at play: you'll have to right click your page, Inspect Element, and post the rendered HTML in your question instead of the ASP.

Answer (score 1):

Like Tyler Roper mentioned, the id for `runat="server"` control is overwritten in DOM.

You can try (if you dont want to use `ClientIdMode="Static"`)

```
alert($("#<%=hdID.ClientID%>").val());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I found my mistake. I incorrectly referenced the  jquery script file location.