# jquery for selecting attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check value for an `<html>` tag's attribute using following jquery code:

```
if ($('[data-theme == "dark"]')) {
        $(".epcBanner").css("url", "(~/Content/Images/EPC-.png)");
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<html data-theme="dark>
```

All I'm trying to check is data-theme's value and above code is not working. How can this be achieved. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `%( <selector> )` returns an object. And any object is always "truthy". You have to check if that jQuery object contains an actual element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if element exists in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)

Comment: I am not checking if element exists or not. I am trying to check element's attribute value equal to something or not. Your link is wrong

Comment: Right now you only have an invalid CSS selector - but with the description my dupe target is still valid. _"I am trying to check element's attribute value."_ -> What element? -> [mcve]

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it answers your question

Comment: Then select the `<html>` tag and then use `.data()`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the element exists, so the condition should be

```
if ($('[data-theme == "dark"]').length > 0)
```

and there is no *url* property: if you are setting a `background` the property is

```
$(".epcBanner").css("background-image", "url(~/Content/Images/EPC-.png)");
```

Comment: And you should use the search because that's an obvious duplicate ;)

Comment: there are two issues with this code. I would be surprised if an exact duplicate existed.

Comment: _"I am trying to check value for an html attribute"_ - And your answer is the same as in the dupe target... o.O

Comment: OK. Lets say I want to check if `data-theme` value is equal to 'dark' or not? How will that be made possible?