# how to deal with a none existent element/id in a html with 1 javascript script on multiple views

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html page, Create and edit. im using javascript. I also use the 'use strict'; rule.

Now i have a select option and i use javascript to manipulate it to insert data and other element-tags in the html. I have 1 option-tag with an id in edit and not in create. I have 1 script and i am using it on both view, but it gives an uncaught error in de create and i don't want to make the same script just for 1 new id. What is the proper way to handle this problem ?

btw this is an example, i do have the same problem on many other pages. I just want to use 1 script, but i am not sure if its the best way to do this. Thnx for the help too <3

Code example:

Create:

```
<label></label>
<select>
     <option></option>
</select>
```

Edit:

```
<label></label>
<select>
     <option id="OptionSelectedId"></option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
let OptionSelectedId = document.getElementById('OptionSelectedId');
```

I have found a solution, i just gave the create page the option with the same id, but i don't want that because its not supposed to be there. I hope i explained good enough.

Comment: `if (!OptionSelectedId)` then exit your function

Comment: Do you have the option to use [tag:jquery] - it handles this for you.

Comment: Here's a solution to check if an element exists: (this vanilla-js answer to a jquery question): https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801201/2181514

Comment: Ooh lol, that was really simple. Thnx RoryMcCrossan and freedomn-m. I tried the js first because i am not using jquery, but i will look more into that.